# .NET Console App How to communicate result via Process object?

Tags: .net, console-application

I am trying to find a robust way to run a console application from a parent process, and have the console app communicate back to the parent process.  So, one way I thought perhaps was to start the console app via a Process object, and have the app modify some property with a result message that could be checked.  I don't know if that is possible, or how you might access a parent process object that instantiated that instance.  Or, if there is a better way to do so.

I am writing in VB.NET Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 3.5.

Certainly I could output a file to the disk containing info, and look for it when the process is done, but that's not as elegant as I would like.

Comment: Well you could just write to the console, and let the "parent" process read the output of the "child" process. It's a bit of a pain, but it's definitely feasible. Or you could do it over sockets or named pipes...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Skeet, this led me to an answer that works.  Here's an example of the code that works:

```
    Dim retrieveArgs As String
    'Set up arguments to pass
    retrieveArgs = "-A -B -C"
    Dim si As New ProcessStartInfo
    si.FileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "MyUtility.exe"
    si.Arguments = retrieveArgs
    si.CreateNoWindow = True
    si.UseShellExecute = False
    'NOTE: You have to redirect StdOut
    si.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(si)

    p.WaitForExit()

    Dim result As String = ""
    While Not p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream
        result = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine
        Logger.WriteLine(fxName, result, Log.MessageTypeEnum.InfoType)
    End While
```